# About server restart with Brain Socket with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

While reading the [Brain Socket's documentation](https://github.com/BrainBoxLabs/brain-socket) I read the following:

> Any changes to your laravel app / code while the ws server is running are not taken into account. You need to restart the ws server to see any of your changes.

I understood why that's needed, but since it quite inconvenient to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and executing `php artisan brainsocket:start` every time, what would be a convenient way to restart the websocket server?

Comment: It's inconvenient for you developing the application, when it's ready you won't need to restart it very often. For development look into a task runner such as [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) to watch for changes to the code, when you save files you can have the taskrunner manage the inconvenient tasks.

Comment: @DavidBarker you should write that as an answer - grunt or gulp would be an excellent solution to this problem!